# AJAX - Picture upload with only an icon (Facebook style)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a picture upload system where you just press the icon >
Windows Explorer opens up > Select a picture > After selecting, the upload process starts
immediately and automatically. However, every time I'm trying to run that code via AJAX, I'm getting `undefined index notice` which can be viewed with "Developer Tools" tab. There's nothing wrong with my PHP, so I'm not posting it in here since the upload process is working just fine without AJAX.

I'm thinking that there might be something wrong with my AJAX code. Any help would be much appreciated! :)

**Here's my markup [HTML]**

```
<div class="event-head" id="hover-card">
        <i class="fa fa-camera" id="upload-event-cover" title="Update your cover"></i>
        <?php $attributes = ['id' => 'update-cover'];?>
        <?php echo form_open_multipart('events/upload_cover_photo', $attributes);?>
            <input type='hidden' name='event_id' value='<?=$event['event_id']?>'/>
            <input type="file" id="event-cover-file" name="userfile" />
        <?php echo form_close();?>
</div>
```

**Here's the AJAX part [JS]**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
// Animate the camera icon everytime user hover's over #hover-card
$("#hover-card").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $("#upload-event-cover").animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, {
            duration: 100,
        });
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $("#upload-event-cover").animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, {
            duration: 100,
        });
    }
});

// Open "Browse" 
$('#upload-event-cover').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('#event-cover-file').click();
});


  $("#event-cover-file").change(function(e) {

    if($(this).val() != "") {

       // Send it via AJAX
        $("form#update-cover").submit(function(e) {
                var from = $(this);

                $.ajax({
                    url: from.attr('action'),
                    type: from.attr('method'),
                    data: { userfile: $('#event-cover-file').val() },
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        from.find(".comment_submit").hide();
                        from.find("#spinner_comment").show();
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data.st == 1) {
                            $("#event-cover-file").html(data);
                        }

                    }, complete: function() {
                        from.find("#spinner_comment").hide();
                        from.find(".comment_submit").show();
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    });    
</script>
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Remove the `,` after `duration: 100`.

Comment: I'm using PHP version 5.5 and I've build my app with CodeIgniter framework

Comment: `from.find(".comment_submit")`? I don't see HTML.

Comment: Check this. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: You do know that you are not setting your submit Event until a change occurs first, right?

Comment: Is the return `data` from your PHP page JSON? If so, how would `$("#event-cover-file").html(data);` work?

Answer (score 0):

Start by changing:

```
$("#hover-card").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $("#upload-event-cover").animate({
        opacity: 1
        }, {
            duration: 100,
        });
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $("#upload-event-cover").animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, {
            duration: 100,
    });
  }
});
```

to

```
var uec = $('#upload-event-cover')
$('#hover-card').mouseenter(function(){
  uec.fadeIn(100);
}).mouseleave(function(){
  uec.fadeOut(100);
});
```

`url: from.attr('action')` means you are submitting JavaScript data to the same PHP page that built your HTML. You would need the proper conditions in PHP on the page for this to work. I recommend that you use a completely different `url` to submit your AJAX to. You usually send AJAX to a `url` that processes JSON data (force with `dataType:'JSON'`) as `$_GET['json_object_property']` or `$_POST['json_object_property']`. `sucess:function(){}` fires after your PHP page (`url` is set to) usually encodes a PHP Associative Array as JSON like: `echo json_encode($assoc_array)`.

Comment: Yeah, did that. The problem is that the AJAX can't get the name of the file I want to upload. Without AJAX it's working, so there's something odd going on with my code.

Comment: I checked my Developer Tools tab and the path for the userfile is following: userfile:C:\fakepath\IMG_0418.JPG.863x516_q85_box-0,225,5184,3324_crop_detail.jpg

Comment: Is the `events` folder in the current folder your PHP page, that generates HTML, is in?